# How to download the blockchain of a single ethereum contract’s address?

Tags: blockchain, storage, windows, get-storage-at, brave-browser

The blockchain required to run ethereum is [several Terabytes large](https://hackernoon.com/the-ethereum-blockchain-size-has-exceeded-1tb-and-yes-its-an-issue-2b650b5f4f62). This means more than 9 years would be required to download it with my connection speed.

In my case, I just want to know if the storage of **a single contract’s address** contains a specific value and in which transaction such value was created.

So how to download **all** key/values pairs of a single contract address ?

Comment: According to [bitinfocharts.com](https://bitinfocharts.com/), current size of Ethereum blockchain is 236.69GB.  This is what you need to download.  Several terabytes probably refer to blockchain state size, i.e. how much disk space the node will occupy on the hard disk.

Comment: You got the other point (otherwise yes my connection was that slow). Laptop with 19Tb of nvme storage aren t common.

Comment: I believe several terabytes is disk requirement for so called “archive” node, that stores not only the current state, but also all the past states.  Normal “fast” node, that regularly purges old states, should use much less disk space.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if some client supports this but at least in theory you could start downloading the blockchain only from a certain block number. As the contract (most likely) won't have transactions into it before it was created you only need to check blocks after that.

If you're saying that the blockchain is several terabytes in size then you must mean an archival node (https://etherscan.io/chartsync/chainarchive). That's the most disk space consuming mode and is mostly useless data for typical scenarios. The typical synchronization mode is fast sync which takes a lot less space - currently around 200GB (https://etherscan.io/chartsync/chaindefault). Different clients offer also even more optimized synchronization modes (such as Geth's light sync) but they are limited in what data they offer.

But in any case I don't think there is any way to only download *some* of the data inside blocks. You have to download a whole block at a time. Once you have downloaded the block you can do all sorts of analysis on it and discard it and/or extract needed information from it and continue on to the next block. This means changes into the client's (node's) code implementation.

Comment: Downloading from August 2015 to July 2019 ? No good… And no I don’t mean an archival node https://hackernoon.com/the-ethereum-blockchain-size-has-exceeded-1tb-and-yes-its-an-issue-2b650b5f4f62

Comment: Also what about the underlying call `web3.eth.getStorageAt()` is using ?

Comment: Ah that rant article. 1) It's 1,5 years old 2) The only understandable reference to the >1TB size clearly states "Parity full archive 1,1TB". As far as I can tell everything tells me that archive nodes are the only nodes which are above 1TB. And as for `getStorageAt` - it's a web3 feature so it can only utilize the data your node has collected. So if your node has downloaded the right data then web3 can show it to you but your node won't start downloading such certain block just because web3 asks for it.

Comment: But you see the point is web3 doesn’t requires to use your own node and as such often run inside the web browser (at least I never had to do it)… Also I’m afraid that I need an archival node for what I need do which is described in the question.

Comment: Well yes, you can point your web3 to any node you have access to. If you point it to somebody else's node (for example Infura) you don't need to worry about downloading the blockchain yourself. But no, you don't need an archival node for just seeing when some value is set in a contract. But, if you have further questions please post a new question

Comment: I always ran web3 in the web3 browser and don’t remember having to set it up against a node address. What do you mean ? Do you think infura.io would let me doing exactly what I need or is it just a web3 provider ?

Comment: When you use `web3` in the web browser, you're probably using MetaMask, and MetaMask is connected to Infura by default. So `web3.eth.getStorageAt()` is calling the `eth_getStorageAt` RPC method on Infura's node. You can read any value in storage this way easily, but I don't know of a shortcut for finding out what transaction _set_ that value. You could do a binary search through blocks until you found the first block with the given value, and then you could process all transactions for that block?

Comment: @smarx In order to perform a binary search, the blocks would have to be downloaded over my connection first and that’s not something possible… Even for only 300Gb it will take months !

Comment: No, you could just use a public node like Infura.

Comment: @smarx as far I know, infura doesn’t provide such method in it’s ᴀᴘɪ for doing a search in blocks.

Comment: I mean that _you_ do the search. `eth_getStorageAt` lets you specify the block you want to query. So you need log(n) queries to find the right block, and then you need to check all the transactions that block.

Comment: @smarx it also requires the index/address in storage. And I don’t know it. There’s 2⁵¹² possible storage addresses and as I don’t know the addresses which aren’t at 0, I can’t process all possible values.

Comment: I think you mean 2^256. But then I'm confused as to what you're trying to do. You don't know where in storage the value is? What _do_ you know?

Comment: I don’t know where to look in storage but I want to know which transaction set a specific value in storage (as I wrote in my question). I mean the date… not the storage address itself.